# What valid cidr can I assign to my GKE cluster?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to set up a subnetwork and a cluster in GCP.

I've successfully created a subnet with the cidr like 10.0.13.0 with a subnet mask of 24.

What I'm confused about is that the examples I've been looking at assign the subnet to the cluster, they also assign a cidr to the cluster too.

Is this cidr a separate subnet, or is it defining a range of IPs within the subnet I created?

If it's the former, what's the point in assigning a subnet to the cluster?  If it's the latter, how do I pick a cidr that's valid?

So far I've just tried assigning the same cidr to both the cluster and the subnet, but gcloud fails to create the cluster if I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a separate subnet. Basically you are choosing the subnetwork to which the GKE cluster belongs to.

By default, once you create new cluster it wil be using routes based network mode. A routes-based cluster has a range of IP addresses that are used for pods and services where
[clusterIPv4Cidr](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/routes-based-cluster#pod_address_range) is called the pod address range and servicesIpv4Cidr for services. You may also view them as secondary ranges

```
-range for pod ip addresses

-range for services ip addresses
```

The goal of assigning a network to your cluster is to determine which other compute engine resources it is able to communicate with.